# How to retrieve Queue object via REST API?

Tags: soql, rest-api, query

Is it possible to retrieve `Queue` object via REST API? I tried to find a way to query for it, but there is no [Standard Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) by that name.

Comment: With this type of question, the quickest way to find out is generally to try to do it yourself. https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php is pretty handy for this type of thing (and saves you the trouble of implementing an OAuth flow yourself). Beyond that, this question is in desperate need of additional details. What are you trying to do with the `Queue` SObject (query rows, get describe information for fields, insert rows, etc...)? What research have you done already?

Comment: I need list of queues, tries workbench - can't find.

Comment: That would be something you should add to your question via an [edit], rather than keep as a comment (comments are best thought of as temporary). My general rule of thumb is that if your question is less than 4 sentences long, it's very likely too short and does not include enough detail.

Comment: Or probably it's pretty simple question, the answer would be like this below "A "queue" is actually represented by a Group record". If I rephrase the question like this "I need list of queues, is it possible to retrieve Queue object via REST API?" would it make a lot difference? I guess not

Comment: Seems pretty unfair this question got 3 down votes as there is a name mixup here. But regardless, I edited the post to demonstrate a bit more research. I think if the question had included a search like the above it might have been more neutrally/positively received.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "queue" is actually represented by a `Group` record. Specifically, groups are only queues when they have `QueueSObject` records configured (that's what allows them to own a specific type of `SObject`). So you should be able to hit the REST API with a query like:

```
/v42.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Group+WHERE+Id+IN+(SELECT+QueueId+FROM+QueueSObject)
```

Comment: simply Type = 'Queue' works

Comment: @SantanuBoral Since your answer already indicated as much it didn't seem right to edit my answer. Also it seems the main point the OP was missing is that the object name is `Group`.

Answer (score 4):

This will give you the result, use `Type = Queue` in the Group object

```
/services/data/v41.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,+Name+FROM+GROUP+WHERE+TYPE+=+'Queue'
```

Workbench will give you this result

[image: QeueeList]